# Composing a draft email from my gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm using the example [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/compose) to guide me as I write code to compose a standalone draft email using user input values from my gmail addon.

Here's the button widget that should create the draft:

```
var submitButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
    .setText('Create Draft')
    .setComposeAction(
        CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("createEmailDraft"),
        CardService.ComposedEmailType.STANDALONE_DRAFT
    );
```

And here's the callback:

```
function createEmailDraft(e) {
    var recipient = e.formInput.recipient;
    var subject = e.formInput.subject;
    var body = e.formInput.body;

    var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, subject, body);
    return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
        .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
}
```

I keep encountering the following error:

```
Access denied: : Missing access token for authorization. Request: MailboxService.CreateDraft.
```

My scopes seem alright (overly permissive if anything):

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
],
```

I would greatly appreciate any help getting past this error!

Answer (score 2):

This one is a bit [deeper in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/compose#example), but you must use the access token in the [callback Action event](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/actions#action_event_objects) to authorize the draft creation:

```
function createEmailDraft(e) {
    var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

    var recipient = e.formInput.recipient;
    var subject = e.formInput.subject;
    var body = e.formInput.body;

    var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(recipient, subject, body);
    return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
        .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Chris. I just tried adding those two lines, but now am running into this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "accessToken" from undefined."

Comment: I added "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata" to the scopes list, since the docs say it's supposed to give me access to messageMetadata. This doesn't work either - e.messageMetadata is still undefined.

Comment: This is an old post and probably long solved or forgotten, but using the following worked for me:
`var accessToken = e.gmail.accessToken;`

Thank you Chris!

Comment: how does this work when there's already a draft? I tried to overwrite it but the gmail UI doesn't seem to show the new draft